# How let the function be directly written as an ordinary synchronous function, and the running result is consistent with the async function

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise

// example

```
async function getUser() {
  console.log("getUser");
  const user = await fetch("https://api.uomg.com/api/rand.qinghua").then(
    (res) => res.json()
  );
  console.log("getUser已获取到用户数据user", user);
  return user;
}

async function m1() {
  console.log("m1");
  return await getUser();
}

async function m2() {
  console.log("m2");
  return await m1();
}

async function m3() {
  console.log("m3");
  return await m2();
}

async function main() {
  console.log("main");
  const user = await m3();
  console.log("feng", user);
}

main();
```

In fact ,async function only **getUser**，but because of it, all subsequent functions become asynchronous.so,How change this?expect your anwser ,Thank u.

In fact ,async function only **getUser**，but because of it, all subsequent functions become asynchronous.so,How change this?expect your anwser ,Thank u.

Comment: Replace `async function m1() {` with `function m1() {` and `return await getUser();` with `return getUser();`. Do the same with `m2` and `m3`.

Comment: @jabaa that doesn't make anything any more synchronous. But the point is, you can't make an async function sync, or call it in a sync way.

Comment: "*because of it, all subsequent functions become asynchronous*" - yes. They are doing something asynchronous, they must return a promise for their result. You cannot change this. Why would you want to?

Comment: @AKX The question is how to write the functions without async/await. At least that's how I understand the title. Nobody wants to make anything synchronous. You can write `m1`, `m2` and `m3` as ordinary synchronous functions.